# Is $L(G) \subseteq L(R)$ decidable?

Tags: regular-languages, context-free, undecidability

Is the following problem decidable?

> Given a context-free grammar $G$ and a regular expression $R$, is $L(G) \subseteq L(R)$?

It is given that the following problem is undecidable

> Given a context-free grammar G, is $ L(G) = \Sigma ^*$ ? $\ (1)$

and this problem decidable

> Given a context-free grammar G, is $ L(G) = \emptyset $ ? $\ \ \ (2)$

My thought is this:

$L(G) \subseteq L(R)$ is the same as $ L(G) \cap \overline{L(R)} = \emptyset $. So, since regular languages are closed under complement, and the intersection of a $CFL$ with a $RL$ is a $CFL$, $L(G) \cap \overline{L(R)}$ is a $CFL$. Now, $(2)$ is decidable, so if we can create a context-free grammar for $L(G) \cap \overline{L(R)}$ and give it as input to a decider for $(2)$ we have decided our initial problem.

Is my thought correct? And if yes, how can create such a grammar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your thought is correct. The only missing part, as you pointed out, is whether or how we can create a CFL algorithmically for the intersection of a CFL with a RL.

If you take a close look at any proof for the fact that the intersection of a CFL with a RL is a CFL, you will find that the proof is constructive or can be made to be constructive easily, giving that there is an algorithm to construct the CFL for a given PDA. Here "constructive" means the same as "algorithmic". It is just by convention or history, we tend to use the word "constructive" instead of "algorithmic" to describe a proof.

You can check your textbook, or [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18642/intersection-of-context-free-with-regular-languages) and [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/99164/is-there-a-simple-proof-that-the-intersection-of-a-cfl-and-a-regular-language).

**Exercise.** Is the following problem decidable?

> Given a context-free grammar $G$ and a regular expression $R$, is $L(G) \supseteq L(R)$?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! About the exercise I would say no, it is not decidable. If it were decidable, given the regular expression  $ (a \cup b)^* $, we would be able to determine if $ \Sigma ^* \subseteq L(G) \Leftrightarrow L(G) = \Sigma ^* $ which is undecidable. So we get a contradiction, thus the initial assumption is false.